# Passing pointers to an array as arguments to a function

Tags: c, parameter-passing

I am trying to implement `INSERTION SORT` here in `C`, which I think I've done successfully. However, I am having problems in `passing arrays as arguments`.

I want in place sorting, which means that the original array passed into the `insertion_sort` function should contain the elements in the sorted array itself.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int * insertion_sort(int *a,int length)
{
    int j;
    for(j=1;j<length;j++)
    {
        int i,key=a[j];
        for(i=j-1;j>=0;j--)
        {
            if(a[i]<=key)
                break;
            a[i+1]=a[i];
        }  
        a[i+1]=key;
    }

    return *a;
}

int main(void)
{
    int a[]={10,12,7,6,9,8};
    insertion_sort(a,6);
    int i;    
    for(i=0; i<6; i++)
       printf("%d\n", a[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**
Nothing gets printed in the output screen.
Help me find the bug here. Thanks !!

Comment: You're not "Passing pointers to an array" here. You're just passing pointers to an int

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.You probably meant to use `i` in the inner loop:

Change:

```
for(i=j-1;j>=0;j--) 
          ^^   ^^
```

to:

```
for(i=j-1;i>=0;i--)
```

2.You don't have to return anything as the original array gets modified (which is just as well since you ignore the returned value).

3.Array index starts from 0. Change outer loop to:     `for(j=0;j<length;j++)`

Comment: Ok.. Thanks.. What if I didn't pass the pointer as the argument. Rather I pass `void insertion_sort(int a[],int length)`. Now If I print the array from the `main` method, will it print the sorted array or the initial array itself ?

Comment: `insertion_sort(int a[],int length)` is same as `insertion_sort(int *a,int length)`. Remove the return statement once you change to `void..` (it's wrong atm).

Comment: I removed the `return` statement.. But if I use `insertion_sort(int a[],int length)` isn't it call by value, where as `insertion_sort(int *a,int length)` is call by reference. Right ??

Comment: And in the outer loop, I can start picking up keys from the second element right, as a one element array is always sorted. So, is there a reason why I should do this `for(j=0;j<length;j++)`??

Comment: Arrays decay into a pointer when you pass to a function. So whether you write it as  `insertion_sort(int a[],int length)` or `insertion_sort(int *a,int length)`, compiler sees them as `insertion_sort(int *a,int length)`